# What is the syntax to get records before/after a date with a Rails "where" method without SQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

what is the syntax to do this without SQL?

```
Subscription.where('end_date > ?', Date.today)
```

i've tried this, but it's obviously incorrect:

```
Subscription.where(:end_date > Date.today)
```

(we are using rails 3) thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using Arel:

```
Subscription.where(Subscription.arel_table[:end_date].gt(Date.today)).all
```

Or by using the gem [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel):

```
Subscription.where(end_date.gt => Date.today).all
```